# Script to clean system

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, cleanup, apt-cache

I want a script to clean my system.

1. Clean unused dependencies.
2. Clean apt-cache.
3. Clean residual-config files.
4. Remove broken packages.
5. Only keep the latest version of packages and remove other. Specially linux-kernel.

And all that you think that the script should contain. Please guide me.
Ubuntu 12.04 with Kernel 3.2.xxxx I exactly don't know.

Comment: Synaptic does a good job of cleaning junk from your system. Set the section to Status and if there is junk, one of the options will be autoclean. You can also get rid of old kernels in the 'local or obsolete' section, but I recommend you keep the one before the current. Also, a residual config files option will appear if you have any. From my experience, it's safe and gives you a cancel option if you're unsure.

Comment: There are some tools and commands in this thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920.

Answer (score 0):

In your favorite editor

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
aptitude purge ~c
aptitude -f
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs apt-get -y purge
```

Make sure you run as root, and you have aptitude installed. Save this file as whatever. However, I do not recommend removing old versions, as sometimes they have legacy items in them. The final line ONLY takes care of linux-kernel (see last sentence why). Even so, I would recommend having multiple kernels just in case one goes BA-ZOINK.

Answer (score 0):

Considering cleaning out old kernelversions, this is something I use regularly:

```
#/bin/bash

#keep the most recent 4 kernels and remove the rest.
sudo apt-get purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-image-\d\S+"| head -n-4 )
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: The first line might not do what you want, be sure not to remove the kernel used by your installation (check with `uname -r`).